# I couldn't verify my identity in Google Play console even though I used my passport and ID card

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I opened my Google Play Console account and paid 25 dollars. I uploaded my passport and ID card to verify my account but it didn't verify my account. I don't understand how it can't verify it when I have real documents.
Which documents do I need to upload?
How can I solve this problem?

I am waiting for your help.

I uploaded my passport and ID card to verify my account but it did not verify my account.